# How to output a string with a space between each letter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

For example, if I entered `I love dogs`, it would need to look like this:

```
I  l o v e  d o g s
```

This code does not do what I need it to do:

```
def spaceitout(source):
    pile = ""
    for letter in source:
        pile = pile+letter
        print pile
    print pile
```

Comment: Hmm... Had this been python 3, I think you could do `print(*'hi!', sep=' ')`. I'm wondering if that is possible.

Comment: @Zizouz212 `python -c "print(*'hi!', sep=' ')"` ->`h i !`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add spaces in-between each letter in string, then not have space at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899068/add-spaces-in-between-each-letter-in-string-then-not-have-space-at-the-end)

Comment: @mayna You've indicated in comments that you've reached a solution. As such, you should select an answer to accept to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
def evenly_spaced(string_,space_= 1):

    import re

    return (' '*space_).join([c for c in re.split(r'(\w)',string_) if c.isalpha()])

print(evenly_spaced(" This a long story ",2))

T  h  i  s  a  l  o  n  g  s  t  o  r  y
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

```
pile = ' '.join(source)
```

This takes the elements of "source" and joins them with a single space as the connector.

If you need only the letters separated, then build the list of letters only, and join that:

```
pile = ' '.join([c for c in source if c.isalpha()])
```

Comment: it will add extra white space for white spaces, and it's not what he wants

Comment: how would i be able to pick the amount of spaces in between each letter like add a count or index

Comment: Note: never do `[c for c in source]`. That's just `list(c)`

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces between letters:

```
def spaceitout(source, count): 
    return (' '*count).join([letter for letter in source.replace(' ','')])
```

Spaces between words:

```
def spaceitout(source, count):
    return (' '*count).join(source.split())
```

Spaces between all chars:

```
def spaceitout(source, count): 
    return (''.join([c + (' '*count) for c in source]).strip())
```

Comment: how would i be able to make it so i can choose the amount of spaces, and now only have them in-between the words.

Comment: That depends on how do you want to handle spaces in between words?  Do you want "i love dogs" to be "i l   o   v   e d  o   g   s"?  What you need/want will dictate how you do it.

Comment: i need it to be, "I   love    dogs"  and I'm choosing the amount of species in-between the words

Comment: My point was, how do you plan on handling preexisting spaces?  You're saying "in between the words", but that's ambiguous here.  Do you mean spaces in between two words, or spaces between the characters in the word? How many spaces should go between two words?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer would be:

```
def spaceitout(source):
    pile = ""
    for letter in source:
        pile = pile + letter + " "
    pile = pile[:-1] #Strip last extraneous space.
    print pile
```

Answer (score 1):

Allows you to specify spaces between words, and spaces between characters.  Based on the answers provided by BigOldTree

```
def space_it(text, word_space=1, char_space=0):
    return (' '*word_space).join([(' '*char_space).join(x) for x in text.split(' ')])
```

Note: This will treat two spaces in the input text as having an "invisible word" between them, change `text.split(' ')` to `text.split()` if this isn't desired.

Answer (score 1):

i think that this is what you was looking for:

```
line = 'I love dogs'
for i in line:
 if i != ' ':
  print i,
 else:
  print '',
```

Answer (score 0):

using itertools:

```
import itertools

def space_word(word, spaces_count=1):
    if spaces_count < 1:
        raise ValueError("spaces_count < 1")

    def space_word_wrapped(word, spaces_count):
        letters = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(word, itertools.cycle(" ")))
        skipped = 0  # have to keep track of how many letter skips
                     # or else from_word starts breaking!
                     # TODO : better implementation of this
        for i, lett in enumerate(letters, start=1):
            from_word = (i + skipped) % 2
            if lett.isspace() and from_word:
                if spaces_count == 1:
                    next(letters)
                    skipped += 1
                    continue       # and skip the space itself
                elif spaces_count == 2:
                    continue       # just count the space
                elif spaces_count == 3:
                    pass           # count everything
                else:          # spaces_count >= 4
                    yield from [" "] * (spaces_count - 3)
            yield lett

    return ''.join(space_word_wrapped(word, spaces_count)).rstrip()
```

It's probably cheaper to just use an iterator here, but I like the generator in a nested function approach. So sue me! :)

Comment: it's a lot of typing for such a simple task

Comment: @BigOldTree sure, I mean, `' '.join(word)` works too, but since OP asked to specify how many spaces there should be....

Comment: i added this part too, it's even shorter

Comment: @AdamSmith Just use `('  '*count).join(word)` for this, as BigOldTree indicated in his answer.

Comment: @BigOldTree well except that yours doesn't work :). OP seems to want to be able to define inter-word spaces, not intra-word spaces. Your second function has no intra-word spaces at all, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @BigOldTree His first function will insert N spaces between characters in a word and ignores the rest.  His second function will insert N spaces between two words, while ignoring spacing between characters in a word.  Exactly what the OP wants is questionable because he's ambiguously using "between words" to mean both "between words" and "between characters in a word"

Comment: @Rejected https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/ae027bd2585ac3422ec0  I agree OP is wording things ambiguously, but paying close attention to his expected output makes things clear.

Comment: @AdamSmith No, that doesn't "make things clear", as evidenced by a varying change in spaces between words with different `space_count` (is that intended, as it doesn't match the provided "expected output" of 2 spaces between words).  Furthermore, your code breaks on `space_count = 1`, outputting `'i l v e d g s '`, outputs an extra space at the end of the string with `space_count` is 2 or 3, and breaks on anything more than that, throwing `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`.

Comment: @Rejected ah you're right! Order of operations is hard. Let me fix the `space_count=1` case. I'm not sure offhand what's happening there.

Comment: @Rejected there we go -- fixed and should handle all corner cases now. The only thing it might balk at is a user defining a non-integer value for `spaces_count`, and that's kind of silly.

Comment: @Rejected note that in comment to BigOldTree above, OP said: "i need it to be, "I love dogs" and I'm choosing the amount of species[sic, spaces?] in-between the words"

Comment: @AdamSmith Then your answer doesn't fulfill the requirements.  No use of your method allows the output of "I love dogs" with spaces between words.  Furthermore, it's still appending an extra space to the end of the outputted string.

Comment: @Rejected The extra space is changed. Picky picky :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm not picky, I'm holding your answer to the same standards in which you felt fair to tell other people that their "answer doesn't work", based on the ambiguity of the question.  As is, your answer still doesn't have a way of fulfilling a required output of both "I  l o v e  d o g s" and a "I love dogs" with a variable spacing between words.  So, as you said, "yours doesn't work :)"

Answer (score 0):

This lists your word( 'his' = ['h','i','s'] and then joins it with a space instead of a comma.

```
def space(word):
   return ' '.join(list(word))
```